# How to select a value from an array when the location is out of bounds?

Tags: java, javascript, python, c++, arrays

I am trying to encrypt some plaintext using a specific method. Given a key [4,5,6,7] and plaintext "This is some plaintext" First letter is T first number in key is 4 thus T becomes X by moving forward  4 (T, U, V, W, X) Next letter is H key is 5 thus H becomes M {H, I, J, K, L, M}

When the end of the key is reached simply start from the beginning and keep encrypting until finished. I have a basic outline in Python:

```
#key = [4,5,12,6,7,11,8,9,1,2,3,10]
key = [4,5,6,7]
letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
plaintext = "IfyouarereadingthisthenthisplanetmayhavehopeafterallYouhavethepowerand"
plaintext = plaintext.upper()
keySpot = 0
count = 0;
keyCount = 0
letterLocation = 0
tempLetter = ""
i = 0

while(count < len(plaintext)):
    tempLetter = plaintext[count]
    for i in range(0, len(letters)):
        if(tempLetter == letters[i]):
            letterLocation = i
        i = i + 1

    if(keyCount > 4):
    keyCount = 0

letterLocation = letterLocation + key[keyCount]
keyCount = keyCount + 1

if(letterLocation > 27):
    #need some logic here so it wont go out of bounds

print letters[letterLocation]
count = count + 1
```

My main problem is what to do if letterLocation is too big when moving forward and gets past Z. When it gets to Z i need it to start over at A and keep going until done. For example If the plaintext letter was Y and the key was 5 Y would become D {Y, Z, A, B, C, D}

How can I do this? It can be in Java, C, C++, JavaScript, or Python whatever is easiest. If you can come up with a better method I'll take advise.

Comment: For beginners, there is an operator in math called modulo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Your problem lacks [MCVE] because you're exposing all sort of things without simplifying it to simply "_When moving forward by a value, how to get past Z and start over at A?_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is quite easy, just use a modulo :

```
letterLocation = (letterLocation + key[keyCount]) % 26
```

Comment: I'm going to test this now, but it looks like it will work! Thank you for taking the time to answer and read over the very hard to explain question

Comment: My code is broken somewhere I guess, it works up to 5 letters then starts acting goofy

Comment: Goofy is not all that helful. Have you still got that '>4' in the code?

Comment: Your indentation seem inconsistent, and you know how important it is in Python. Please post the code indented exactly as it is in your program (for example your letterCount incrementation should be identeed by one tab).